# Problems with bulk mailing phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a working mailer script which has already started sending out mails. We need to send an email message to approximately 5,000 email addresses. I have a few problems though.

1.) It's sending out really slow. I'm guessing it's the embedding? The image is 300+kb big, is it supposed to slow the sending down like that? The mail is sending like 3 emails per minute. And it's going to take a lot of time if we want to send the email to 5000 recipients. The code is something like this:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("rocks.png", "my-attach", "rocks.png");
$mail->Body = 'Embedded Image: <img src="cid:my-attach">
```

2.) We have registered for an smtp which will not limit us to 100 emails per day. It's something like pay as you go and it keeps track of the messages sent. When I checked the log, there were duplicated messages. There were some recipients which were sent twice, the weird thing is it just tries to send the message twice and then moves to the next email addresses. The problem about that is that it consumes our limit from the smtp service and also adds too many queues in the mail which makes the sending even longer. My send code is something like:

```
if(isset($fromaddress)){
do{
$mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
$mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result));
}
```

And my query is something like :

```
SELECT * from email where id > 200
```

You may be wondering about my query. I was in need of having to send the mails from where it left off from timing out due to connection problems so I made a id column and I assign the number as the id of the last email address the mail was sent to. I don't know if that was wise but that was what I had at the moment. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use an SMTP server? Which is it? For instance gmail server don't allow more than 100 email deliveries or maybe more per day.

Comment: We use our own domain smtp. it's not on gmail but it also has a limit that's why we bought the pay as you go service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depending on how PHPMailer is built, yes, it may very well slow it down so much. The reason is pretty simple: if you're mailing as an attachment, the mail call has to know the exact byte size of the mail. It does this by preparing it, which includes reading the image in its entirety. This is a pretty small delay on one email, but if it has to do it 5000 times... Consider queueing and a worker approach.
2. Add a field to your database, call it `mailSent`, type BIT. Every time you send one, set it to 1 for the appropriate row. To select emails, `SELECT * FROM mails WHERE mailSent='0' LIMIT 100`.

Comment: it's not an attachment but an embedding but I'm not sure if there is a difference in this case.

Comment: In terms of mail format, they're one and the same. If you were hotlinking, you'd get away with reading 5000 times 300kb.

Comment: I guess you're right. I did suggest that but the company I'm working for didn't want to to this -.- 
Anyways about number 2, is my query not okay to go with? It's already sent 2000 emails now and I don't know how I can mark all those sent one by one :/ but if you have any suggestions, I'm open to it

Comment: Ultimately, the way you're doing it is fine. However, what I suggested ties in with the last sentence of my answer to point 1: consider a worker approach, especially if you get timeouts! Get workers to do the work, and get a database telling them what to do (a queue of sorts). They do something successfully, they pop it off the queue (or flag it as done). My table structure allows you to do this - it's a good idea for the future :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. Will do that in the future! Maybe you have any ideas as to why the mails duplicate?

Comment: How do I change the value from 0 to 1 if the mail is sent in the loop?

Comment: Define "duplicate". As for setting to 0 or 1 - UPDATE statement within the loop?

Comment: My code is posted here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619682/update-rows-in-a-while-loop-php#comment18682897_13619682) it does mark the first entry in the database but doesn't for the rest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the answer to part 2 of your question, but is there a good reason for you using a do-while loop rather than a while?

From what I can see of your code, the first iteration will try to add an email address from `$row['email']` before $row has been set?

Something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
    //etc
}
```

should work better for you.

Not sure if this should be a comment rather than an answer, but then I can't comment yet anyhow.

Comment: I guess I kinda got used to doing do while since I'm using Dreamweaver and it generates loops like that.